# Dynamically created Control rendered via HtmlTextWriter is not fireing events

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, code-behind

I have a simple ASP.Net page with a button and a Literal Control on it. On button click i am generating a new dynamic control (imagebutton) and rendering it via HtmlTextWriter to the Literal. On control creation i am also adding an onClick Event which is not getting fired. Here is my code:

**aspx**

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnCreate_Click" />
    <asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

**cs**

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton dynBtn = new ImageButton();
        dynBtn.ID = "1";
        dynBtn.ImageUrl = "http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/matte-blue-and-white-square-icons-symbols-shapes/118240-matte-blue-and-white-square-icon-symbols-shapes-power-button.png";
        dynBtn.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(dynBtn_click);
        lit.Text = RenderControl(dynBtn);
    }

    private void dynBtn_click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Response.Write("hello!");
    }

    private string RenderControl(Control control)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        control.RenderControl(writer);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

The control is getting created without any errors but the event is not fireing.

Comment: try adding control to Literal instead of text

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
lit.Controls.Add(dynBtn);
```

Comment: adding some more info on why you think this helps,will help future users

Comment: This does not work cause Literas cannot have sub controls like page.controls.add(mycontrol) ...

Comment: use a Panel to try this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Adding your ImageButton to an ASP.NET container would make your life easier, and would be more in line with the way of doing things in the framework. You can add your button to different types of Web controls, depending on the type of HTML container that you want.

**Option 1 - PlaceHolder**

A PlaceHolder is not rendered as an HTML element. Its output contains only the controls that have been added to it. Among the 3 container controls presented here, it is the most similar to the Literal control.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="container" runat="server" />
```

**Option 2 - Panel**

A Panel is rendered as as `div` element.

```
<asp:Panel ID="container" runat="server" />
```

**Option 3 - Label**

A Label is rendered as a `span` element.

```
<asp:Label ID="container" runat="server" />
```

**Adding the control**

The following statement can be used in code-behind to add the ImageButton to any of the 3 types of ASP.NET containers mentioned above:

```
container.Controls.Add(dynBtn);
```